# How call Core Foundation functions with Cocoa and not Carbon

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I've got a lot of mature C++ software, building in XCode for Mac, that is calling Core Foundation functions such as `CFBundleCreate()` and `CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey()`.  Many of the CF functions I use are not "toll bridge free".   My XCode7 project currently uses Cocoa, CoreFoundation and Carbon frameworks; and the source has  `#include "Carbon/Carbon.h"`.

I want to use Cocoa only, and eliminate Carbon.  But eliminating `#include Carbon.h` causes all usages of Core Foundation data and functions (CFxxxxx) to produce compile-time errors:  `"Unknown type name"` `"Undeclared identifier"` etc.   I understand that there may be alternative ways to code these operations using NSxxxx functions within Objective C, but that would be a *lot* of work, so I prefer to use C++ and call CFxxxxx functions.

My question is:  How can I call CFxxxx() functions in C++ code using only Cocoa framework (and without Carbon framework or Carbon headers)?

Comment: How do you eliminate Carbon? Have you tried `#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`?

Comment: @kennytm:  Thanks, that fixed it.   I originally deleted the #include Carbon.h .. and that resulted in the compilation errors.  I tried replacing it with #include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> but that  did not help.   <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> does the trick.  Thanks!